# PHP & Curl - Dealing with XML response

Tags: php, xml, curl

hopefully someone can help.

The script below is a simple PHP and Curl script and basically when I echo the response I get the information back but obviously before I encode it for Json.
The below is my PHP and the $response is working fine, however I cannot get an output from $reponse2

My issue is i want to echo the lower

```
 $response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;

$ob = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($ob);
$response2 = json_decode($json, true);

echo $response2;

$TRACKINGData = $response2['trackingdetails'];

for($i=0;$i<count($TRACKINGData);$i++) { 
    echo 'Tracking details: ' .$TRACKINGData[$i]['trackingnumber'].''; 
    
    } ?>


 for($i=0;$i<count($TRACKINGData);$i++) { 
    echo 'Tracking details: ' .$TRACKINGData[$i]['trackingnumber'].''; 
    
    } ?>
```

Please see the response i get from Postman `

```
<trackingresponse>
    <trackingdetails>
        <trackingdetail>
            <trackingnumber>4569788591</trackingnumber>
            <parcelnumber>15504569788591</parcelnumber>
            <consignmentnumber>4569788591</consignmentnumber>
            <deliveryaddress1></deliveryaddress1>
            <deliveryaddress2>Bramble Wood</deliveryaddress2>
            <deliverylocality>1Street</deliverylocality>
            <deliverycity></deliverycity>
            <deliverypostcode></deliverypostcode>
            <deliverycountrycode>GB</deliverycountrycode>
            <etastart>1970-01-01T12:31:00+01:00</etastart>
            <etaend>1970-01-01T13:31:00+01:00</etaend>
            <parcelcode>15504569788591*19990</parcelcode>
            <trackingevents>
                <trackingevent>
                    <date>2022-09-24T08:32:00+01:00</date>
                    <code>15</code>
                    <type>OUT FOR DELIVERY</type>
                    <description>On vehicle for delivery between 12:31 - 13:31 Out For Delivery SMS notification sent</description>
                    <locality>Peterborough</locality>
                    <countrycode>GB</countrycode>
                    <etastart>12:31</etastart>
                    <etaend>13:31</etaend>
                    <imagekey></imagekey>
                </trackingevent>
                <trackingevent>
                    <date>2022-09-24T00:36:00+01:00</date>
                    <code>4</code>
                    <type>CONFIRMED AT DEPOT</type>
                    <description>Confirmed at depot</description>
                    <locality>Peterborough</locality>
                    <countrycode>GB</countrycode>
                    <imagekey></imagekey>
                </trackingevent>
                <trackingevent>
                    <date>2022-09-24T00:17:00+01:00</date>
                    <code>4</code>
                    <type>CONFIRMED AT DEPOT</type>
                    <description>Confirmed at depot</description>
                    <locality>Peterborough</locality>
                    <countrycode>GB</countrycode>
                    <imagekey></imagekey>
                </trackingevent>
                <trackingevent>
                    <date>2022-09-23T20:01:00+01:00</date>
                    <code>9</code>
                    <type>HUB SCAN</type>
                    <description>Confirmed at Hub</description>
                    <locality>Hub 3 - Bham</locality>
                    <countrycode>GB</countrycode>
                    <imagekey></imagekey>
                </trackingevent>
                <trackingevent>
                    <date>2022-09-23T18:34:00+01:00</date>
                    <code>0</code>
                    <type>PARCEL DATA</type>
                    <description>Customer data received</description>
                    <locality>Birmingham</locality>
                    <countrycode>GB</countrycode>
                    <imagekey></imagekey>
                </trackingevent>
            </trackingevents>
        </trackingdetail>
    </trackingdetails>
</trackingresponse>`
```

Comment: First, what exactly is your expected output from the sample xml? Second, why bother with json conversion when you can extract it directly from the xml?

Comment: Is your curl not working or is that part fine, just the rest? It seems to be working. If so, you don’t have a curl problem, that is just a thing that happened before and now you’ve got XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn’t bother with the JSON, it can actually mess with you if you ever have complex XML. Instead, SimpleXML makes it really easy to access nodes or iterate over them:

```php
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// if you actually think you will get multiple
foreach($obj->trackingdetails->trackingdetail as $trackingDetail){
    echo $trackingDetail->trackingnumber;
}

echo PHP_EOL;

// if you know you'll always have just one
echo $obj->trackingdetails->trackingdetail->trackingnumber;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/THok5

Comment: You thief.  I posted a  day after you and had the green check (whatever that's called).  Then I had to evacuate due to t he hurricane and I return home to find  I have been upended by the "God's Country Guy".   Just kidding.  I was born in WI.  C#?  I once upon a time owned the sharpsoftware.com domain.  The logo was the Chevy Super Sport emblem.  I still do not like Microsoft.  Even more than I deplore third party PHP IDEs.  I use PHP, HTML, CSS, and a little JavaScript with no third party anything.

Answer (score 0):

$response2 is an array, not a string.  Convert $response2 to a string before the echo.

```
echo var_export($response2,true);
```